# Golang - convert array / map to JSON

Tags: json, go

I am trying to convert a map[] to JSON so I can post it as part of a request. But my map[] has various types including strings / ints.

I currently have:

```
mapD := map[string]string{"deploy_status": "public", "status": "live", "version": 2}
mapB, _ := json.Marshal(mapD)
fmt.Println(string(mapB))

//output
prog.go:17: cannot use 2 (type int) as type string in map value
```

How do I make it so that I can include strings and ints within the same map?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use map[string]interface{} :

```
mapD := map[string]interface{}{"deploy_status": "public", "status": "live", "version": 2}
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/G47FWxGILk)

Comment: Thanks I was missing the {} before then opening the {} again :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a value of type `int` as a string, but your map is defined as `[string]string`. You have to modify the first line as:

```
mapD := map[string]string{"deploy_status": "public", "status": "live", "version": "2"}
```

If you do not know the type of the values, you can use `interface{}` instead.

Comment: I can't change the int to a string as this would be invalid on the request side so it has to stay an int.

Comment: If I do the interface version:

mapD := map[string]interface{"deploy_status": "public", "status": "live", "version": 2}
mapB, _ := json.Marshal(mapD)
fmt.Println(string(mapB))

I get the error of: syntax error: unexpected string literal

Comment: Yes, because you're not initializing the interface correctly.You should use `map[string]interface{}{...}`